# Inequality containing finite sum.

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

For what value of k the following inequality holds?

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^3<k|\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}|$

I don't have any idea to solve this.

Comment: How to try to solve this?Any hint,technique.

Comment: There is no constant $k$ that will work for all $a_i$. Is there an additional condition that has been left out?

Comment: No,no condition

Comment: @AndréNicolas But if we suppose some condition for example convergence of sequence $a_i$ or convergence of series or any other condition,then what you can do.May be your idea will help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no constant $k$ that will work for all $a_i$. Take for example $a_i=c\gt 0$ for all $i$. Then the left-hand side is $nc^3$, while the right-hand side is $k\sqrt{nc}$. Whatever number $k$ we pick, by choosing $c$ large enough, we can make $nc^3$ bigger than $k\sqrt{nc}$.

Comment: Yes you are right,but if we want the series should be convergent then will it affect the answer?

Comment: Presumably $n$ is fixed, so there is no issue of convergence. But it certainly is true that if the $a_i$ are "small" positive (say less than $1$) there will be a constant that depends on $n$ but such that the inequality holds.